# Configuring device's wifi settings through SSH

Tags: wifi, configuration

I just unpackaged a NVIDIA Jetson TX2 running Ubuntu 16.04 today and I am connecting to it with SSH while it's plugged in to my router via ethernet.

I'd like to configure the TX2 to automatically connect to my wifi network so the physical connection is not necessary.

I was hoping that copying my wifi config file located at `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` to the same location on the TX2 would be sufficient -- after running `nmap` to list hosts connected to my network, I'm now seeing that this is probably embarrassingly naive.

Is there a way I can, through an SSH connection alone, setup the TX2 to automatically connect to my wifi on boot?

Edit: I'm seeing posts like [this one](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address/37921#37921) and [this one](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/47177/how-to-automatically-connect-to-wifi-on-boot-for-pi2) which seem like they might lead me down the right path (modifying `/etc/network/interfaces`), but I honestly have no idea what I'm doing...

Comment: You could try `nmtui`, which is a text based front-end to NetworkManager.

Answer (score 0):

User `chili555` answered my question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412325/automatically-connect-to-a-wireless-network-using-cli).

Append the following to `etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
wpa-essid SSID_Name
wpa-psk XXXXX
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.1
```